# What's the rule of binarysation for java.awt.image.BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage, color-space

I can use this code

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("toolbar.png"));
BufferedImage grayImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
Graphics graphics = grayImage.getGraphics();
graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
graphics.dispose();
```

to convert a BufferedImage from TYPE_3BYTE_BGR to TYPE_3BYTE_BGR.

For example , the input:

[image]

the output:

[image]

I know that the colored pixel is turned into a white pixel or a black pixel based on a computation rule. What's it and what can I do to adjust it? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion as in your code above, is an implicit conversion happening, because the input image (RGB) has more colors that the destination (binary indexed color).

The "rule" for this conversion to binary color can be described as simply "pick the color in the destination that is closest to the one from the input ". As your only colors are black and white, all colors that have the average of R, G and B less than 50% will become black, the rest white. There is no way to "adjust" this, directly.

However, you can control the threshold, either directly or compute it from the input, for better images. See for example [this blog](http://zerocool.is-a-geek.net/java-image-binarization/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by saying "average of R, G and B less than 50%". Assume we use the BGR24 type. Does it mean "(value of R + value of G + value of B) / 3 < 255 / 2"?